# Xcode 7 - removing annoying warnings?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7

After rearranging a project I'm getting many warnings about missing files.  However, from the file browser they do exist and the links are correctly linked up from the GUI side.

Unfortunately, when I build the project I get many warnings about missing files like AppDelegate etc.  The file is not red in the browser and the build completes and the project runs.

Why am I getting these warnings and how can I get rid of them?  I'm not happy seeing warnings.  Especially since there are 47 of them for a very small project.

---

EDIT:

It turns out the issue was related to version control.  As I was moving the project into a directory that was already under version control.  XCode has this feature built in but and was causing some problems.

In the preferences I simply unchecked `Enable Source Control` in the `Source Control section`

Comment: Did you try removing the files and adding them again? Also, what sort of "rearrangement" did you do?

Comment: Did you check the "Compile sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources" build phases in Xcode? Any clues there?

Comment: Actually I'm finding it does it if you simply copy a whole project from one directory to another and then open the copy.

Which would be the case if someone were to check out the project from source control to a different path.  Highly likely if their username is different.

Comment: Very very strange.  It's picking up something that is cached or doesn't like the path or something.  If I copy the project to a particular path, it has errors.  Some of the paths don't exist.  Well that makes sense.  But if I copy it to a completely different location it is fine.  It's a mystery. Do you know where xcode might store history about past projects?

Comment: Sounds like some stuff is being referenced by absolute paths (I still don't understand how that could be the case)? Did you try opening the xcode project file in a text editor and see what it says?

Comment: Ahh, I know what the problem is.  I have other directories that contain source files relative to the project file.  It's complaining that those don't exist even though they haven't been directly added to the project.  How do I correct that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96506/discussion-between-nicolasmiari-and-matt).